# Unexpected behavior of the `Where` clause

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following Linq statement which is used to retrieve the list of all rows in the table which satisfy a particular condition.

```
var set = db.TcSet
    .Where(x => x.SetName.Equals(original.SetName))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.SetName == original.SetName))
```

This particular statement is used to edit all entities in the table with a particular name. So the initial name of the property is retrieved in the `original` and checked for all other entries in the database which matches the condition.

**Current Output**

If I have two entries with the name `Play123` and Edit one of the entry the output of the `where query` only contains one element.

If there is an entry `Play123` and `Play1234`, and I try to edit `Play123` to `Play1234` , the output of the `where query` contains two elements : `Play123` and  `Play1234` .

What am I missing that results in this unexpected behavior.

**Update**

```
var original = db.TcSet.Find(tcSet.TcSetID);
foreach (var set in db.TcSet
    .Where(x => x.SetName.Equals(original.SetName))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.SetName == original.SetName)))
{
    if (set.SetName == original.SetName) // This was added again due to the unexpected behavior
    {
           set.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
           set.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
           set.PhysicalUnit = tcSet.PhysicalUnit;

           db.Entry(set).State = EntityState.Modified;

           db.Entry(set).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
           db.Entry(set).Property(x => x.CreatedOn).IsModified = false;
           db.Entry(set).Property(x => x.TechnicalCharacteristicID).IsModified = false;
    }      

}
```

Now I have solved the problem by iterating through all the elements in the table which I know isn't the best practice.

**Working code**

```
   var editlist = db.TcSet.Where(x => x.SetName == original.SetName).AsEnumerable().Where(x=>x.SetName==original.SetName).ToList();

  foreach(var set in editlist)
      // do save
```

When I removed the if condition it worked.

Comment: How do you edit the entries?

Comment: We might need a bit more code to get a better picture of what you're trying to do.

Comment: i will add the Edit controller logic in the code..

Comment: You can use where like this i might helps you
'db.TcSet.Where(x => x.SetName.toLower().Count(original.SetName))
.AsEnumerable().Where(x=> x.SetName.toLower().Count(original.SetName))'

Comment: @ImranLuhur: That is not an expected behavior. I need to treat `ABC` and `abc` differently. My `where`  after the `AsEnumerable` is to serve that purpose.

Comment: @Vini,  don't see any editing going on in your code. Can you post that part too?

Comment: @devuxer: I have added the edit part in the code. But my issue is with the results of the Where query. Or do you want me to post the whole function of Edit?

Comment: @Vini, You seem to be using the `Where` clause correctly (although you should only need the `==` one, not the `Equals` one), so something must be wrong elsewhere. Perhaps there's a mistake in your testing procedure, or you are running your test against a different copy of the database than you are using to run the queries against. You might want to try using something like LINQPad to isolate the problem.

Comment: @devuxer: i changed the query with `==` , and also removed the `if`statement. now it works. But I had a situation where the first time was able to edit all instances of `ABC` to `abc` but when i tried to revert it back it never worked. I really do not understand what was going wrong.. there aren`t any issues with my database..

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a case-insensitive check in your first .Where() clause, if you are to treat `abc` and `ABC` differently.

```
var set = db.TcSet
    .Where(x => x.SetName.Equals(original.SetName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

I would also suggest to cache the results before iterating in the foreach, as you are **changing the source list while iterating through it** which is never a good idea.

```
var original = db.TcSet.Find(tcSet.TcSetID);
var sets = db.TcSet
    .Where(x => x.SetName.Equals(original.SetName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .ToList();

foreach (var set in sets)
{
   set.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
   set.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
   set.PhysicalUnit = tcSet.PhysicalUnit;

   db.Entry(set).State = EntityState.Modified;

   db.Entry(set).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
   db.Entry(set).Property(x => x.CreatedOn).IsModified = false;
   db.Entry(set).Property(x => x.TechnicalCharacteristicID).IsModified = false;
}
```